# What is the Interpretation of This Field Operator: $\vec{X} = \int \pi \vec{x} \phi \operatorname{d}^3 x$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, klein-gordon-equation

In scalar quantum field theory the field momentum operator is constructed from the canonical field operators, $\phi$ and $\pi$, in the equation:
[$$P_j = -\int \pi \partial_j \phi \operatorname{d}^3x.$$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor#Scalar_field)

As long as the field operators obey the equal time commutation relations, $\left[ \phi\left(\vec{x}\right),\pi\left(\vec{y}\right)\right] = i \delta\left(\vec{x}-\vec{y}\right)$, it is possible to show that the following operator:
$$X_j = \int \pi x_j \phi \operatorname{d}^3x ,$$
obeys the commutation relation $[X_j,P_k] = i\delta_{jk}$.

In detail:
$$\begin{align}
X_j P_k & = -\int \pi(y) y_j \phi(y) \operatorname{d}^3y \int \pi(x) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} \phi(x) \operatorname{d}^3x \\
& = -\int \operatorname{d}^3 x \operatorname{d}^3 y \left(\pi(y) y_j \left[i \delta\left(\vec{x}-\vec{y}\right) +\pi(x) \phi(y)\right] \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} \phi(x)\right) \\
& = -i \int \operatorname{d}^3 x\, \pi(x) x_j \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} \phi(x) \\
&\hphantom{=} - \int \operatorname{d}^3 x \operatorname{d}^3 y\, \left(\pi(x) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}\left[-i\delta\left(\vec{x}-\vec{y}\right) + \phi(x) \pi(y) \right] y_j \phi(y)\right)\\
& = -i \int \operatorname{d}^3 x\, \pi(x) x_j \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} \phi(x) + i \int \operatorname{d}^3 x \operatorname{d}^3 y\, \pi(x) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} \delta\left(\vec{x}-\vec{y}\right) y_j \phi\left(\vec{y}\right) + P_k X_j\\
& = -i \int \operatorname{d}^3 x\, \pi(x) x_j \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} \phi(x) - i \int \operatorname{d}^3 x \operatorname{d}^3 y\, \pi(x) \frac{\partial}{\partial y_k} \delta\left(\vec{x}-\vec{y}\right) y_j \phi\left(\vec{y}\right) + P_k X_j\\
& = -i \int \operatorname{d}^3 x\, \pi(x) x_j \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} \phi(x) + i \int \operatorname{d}^3 x \operatorname{d}^3 y\, \pi(x) \delta\left(\vec{x}-\vec{y}\right) \frac{\partial}{\partial y_k} \left[ y_j \phi\left(\vec{y}\right)\right] + P_k X_j\\
& = i \delta_{jk} + P_k X_j .
\end{align}$$

What is the physical interpreation of $X_j$?

Comment: You've just written down the infinite-dimensional [Jordan map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_map) of the Heisenberg algebra, of course. The quantum fields are all but a red herring: they are just infinite vectors of oscillators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. As [Cosmas Zachos](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/66086/cosmas-zachos) comments, the fact that your $X_j,P_i$ fulfill the same commutation relations as the usual non-relativistic position and momentum operators is not surprising. The map $\mathcal{o}\mapsto \mathcal{O} := \int \pi \mathcal{o} \phi\mathrm{d}x$ for an operator $\mathcal{o}$ in the position representation is a infinite-dimensional variant of the [Jordan map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_map), $\mathcal{o}$ being considered as an "infinite-dimensional matrix".
2. $X_j$ is a "position operator" with respect to the $P_i$ at the chosen timeslice only in so far as it fulfills the correct commutation relation *in that timeslice*. However, it does not behave correctly under Poincaré transformations since you are missing a zeroth component to make it a proper 4-vector. For the $P_i$ the Hamiltonian $H = P^0$ naturally fulfills this role, using $p^0 = \sqrt{\vec p^2 + m^2}$ to write $P^\mu = \int p^\mu a^\dagger(\vec p) a(\vec p)\mathrm{d}^3 \vec p$. No such thing is possible for the $X_j$ - there is no time operator. Therefore, your definition of the $X_i$ is frame-dependent and not properly covariant; therefore they *have* no "physical interpretation" in a fully relativistic field theory. Everything you construct in the naive Hamiltonian formalism of relativistic QFT must be checked for its covariance properties; it is crucial and a priori non-trivial that the usual derivations done in textbooks yield covariant results while using non-covariant steps.
3. Attempting to make the construction of position operators $[X_i,P_j] = \mathrm{i}\delta_{ij}$ Lorentz covariant is generally doomed to failure, see e.g. [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/142454/50583) by  Valter Moretti and links therein.

Comment: "No such thing is possible for the $X_j$ - there is no time operator." Is that proven (e.g. by showing it leads to a contradiction), or "no known"?

Comment: @SeanLake The Hamiltonian must be bounded below for a ground state to exist, but an operator fulfilling the canonical commutation relations with another cannot be bounded below, this statement is known as *Pauli's theorem*.

Answer (score -2):

Interpreting $X_j$ as the position operator seems to contradict the interpretation of $\phi^2(x)$ as a probability density — note that his is a real scalar field, so complex conjugation is unnecessary, but a parallel development is possible for a complex scalar field. The answer to that is: it does, and that's because the correct probability density isn't given by $\phi^2(x)$ for a free scalar field.

If we define the spatial Fourier transform of a function as $\tilde{f}(\mathbf{k}) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3/2}} \int \operatorname{d}^3 x\, f(\mathbf{x}) \operatorname{e}^{-i \mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}$ (i.e. symmetric convention), then the free Klein-Gordon field the momentum space annihilation operators are given by:
$$\begin{align}
a(k) &\equiv \sqrt{\frac{\omega}{2 }} \left(\tilde{\phi}(\mathbf{k}) + \frac{i}{\omega} \tilde{\pi}(\mathbf{k})\right)\\
\omega &\equiv \sqrt{\mathbf{k}^2 + m^2},
\end{align}$$
giving a Hamiltonian:
$$H = \int \operatorname{d}^3 k\, \omega \left(a^\dagger(\mathbf{k})\, a(\mathbf{k}) + \frac{1}{2} \left[a(\mathbf{k}),\, a^\dagger(\mathbf{k})\right]\right).$$
The Hamiltonian leads directly to the definition of the particle number operator as:
$$N = \int \operatorname{d}^3k\, a^\dagger(\mathbf{k})\, a(\mathbf{k}).$$
Backing out to write this in terms of the real space field operators:
$$\begin{align}
N & = \int \operatorname{d}^3k\, \frac{\omega}{2}\left(\tilde{\phi}^2(\mathbf{k}) + \frac{1}{\omega^2} \tilde{\pi}^2(\mathbf{k}) + \frac{i}{\omega}\left[\tilde{\phi}(\mathbf{k}),\, \tilde{\pi}(\mathbf{k})\right]\right).
\end{align}$$
This expression for $N$ is identical, classically, to $\int \tilde{\pi}(\mathbf{k}) \tilde{\phi}(\mathbf{k}) \operatorname{d}^3k = \int \pi(\mathbf{x}) \phi(\mathbf{x}) \operatorname{d}^3x$. The relashionship follows from the classical dropping of commutators and applying the equations of motion:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial t^2} &= \nabla^2 \phi - m^2 \phi \Rightarrow \\
i \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} & = \sqrt{m^2 - \nabla^2} \phi,\ \mathrm{and} \\
\pi & = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}.
\end{align}$$

Thus, because the probability interpretation of vanilla "first quantization" quantum mechanics is classical with respect to quantum field theory, it is not a stretch to say that the probability density for a Klein-Gordon particle at $\mathbf{x}$ is given by $\pi(\mathbf{x}) \phi(\mathbf{x}) = \dot{\phi}(\mathbf{x})\phi(\mathbf{x})$, and not $\phi^2(\mathbf{x})$.

Comment: What do you mean by first quantization quantum mechanics?

Comment: If you want to talk about the illness of relativistic position operator, you can check the following books:

1. An Interpretive Introduction to Quantum Field Theory by Paul Teller 

https://www.amazon.com/Interpretive-Introduction-Quantum-Field-Theory/dp/0691016275

2. The Dirac Equation by Bernd Thaller

http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-662-02753-0

3. Theory of Group Representations and Applications by A Barut

http://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/0352

Comment: There is no Second Quantization! And it does not make any sense to say things like {"First Quantization" quantum mechanics is classical wrt QFT.} This sentence does not even make any physical sense.

Comment: Could you please check the book "Theory of Group Representations and Applications" by A Barut? Chapter 20 Applications of Induced Representations, Section 1, Relativistic Position Operator.

Comment: BTW, there is a simpler explanation why you cannot have wave function localized in spacetime. You quantize the relativistic field via finding the unitary representation of the Poincare algebra, in which in can define the 1-particle state of momentum $p$. You may then think of the Fourier transform to obtain the wave function localized in position, but the relativistic invariant integral measure spoils such an attempt. The spacetime position in relativistic field theory is simply a label of the dynamical variables. Localized wavefunction makes sense only in Schroedinger field!

Comment: And your "Schroedinger equation" does not make sense either. This is well-explained in the book Quantum Field Theory for Mathematicians by R. TICCIATI. The equation you wrote down is not consistent

Comment: Relativistic QFT is, in some sense, the unitary representation of the Poincare algebra. There is no generator of translation in momentum space in the Poincare algebra. You have the localized wave function in non relativistic quantum mechanics only because you can do the Fourier transform from momentum space to position space in Euclidean space. In relativistic QFT, we only study the S-matrix, whose initial and final states are given with specific momenta. In addition, the book first book I listed above also pointed out that localized wave function is inconsistent with uncertainty principle.